# EpiServer Basic Filtering of Arbitrary Amount of Values

Tags: c#, .net, search, episerver

Consider the following search:

```
return SearchClient.Instance.UnifiedSearchFor(Request.Query)
.Filter(x => ((IContent)x).Ancestors().Match([ANCESTOR ID]))
.GetResult();
```

This works fine, as long as there is only one `ANCESTOR ID` to match with. There aren't, there are multiple - but I'm not sure of how many exactly.

How can I perform multiple filters on this result set?

**What I've Tried**

```
var query = SearchClient.Instance.UnifiedSearchFor(Request.Query);

[ANCESTOR IDS].ForEach(o => query.Filter(x => ((IContent)x).Ancestors().Match(o.ToString())));

return query.Skip(offset).GetResult();
```

This doesn't appear to work, the filter isn't applied. I assume that's because of the way the methods are chained!?

Any help massively appreciated. Bounty on the table for anyone who helps me crack it.

**What Else I've Tried**

```
    var ancestorFilterBuilder = SearchClient.Instance.BuildFilter<MyPageType>();

    foreach (var ancestorID in ancestorIDs)
    {
        ancestorFilterBuilder.Or(o => o.Ancestors().Match(ancestorID.ToString()));
    }
.....

SearchClient.Instance.UnifiedSearchFor(Request.Query)
                        .Filter(ancestorFilterBuilder)......
```

This didn't successfully filter either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd convinced myself I'd misunderstood the EpiServer API, when in fact my approach of dynamically building a filter was correct, aside from the reassigning of the additional `Or` calls to the filter itself (inspired by Ted's reminder to do so in the context of the other loop I was using):

```
var ancestorFilterBuilder = SearchClient.Instance.BuildFilter<MyPageType>();

foreach (var ancestorID in ancestorIDs)
{
    ancestorFilterBuilder = ancestorFilterBuilder.Or(o => o.Ancestors().Match(ancestorID.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to re-assign `query` in your `ForEach` loop.

Looks like you´re not using the return value, meaning your `query` object is unmodified by the loop.

```
[ANCESTOR IDS].ForEach(o => query = query.Filter(x => ((IContent)x).Ancestors().Match(o.ToString())));
```

Comment: Hmm, no dice unfortunately. Filter returns a different type than query is, I may have to use another variable. This is beginning to feel a little clunky though, I'm pretty sure I'm missing an OOTB solution for this.

Comment: Ah, yes, since you already invoked `UnifiedSearchFor`. I'm no expert on `UnifiedSearch`, but for standard searches you apply filters before the search (using the `For` method). I'm sure you've looked at this: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/9/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Unified-search/